# groovy lang Missing Property Exception

Tags: groovy

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: scope for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask